# Why isn't my image tag working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the different with

```
<images src="http://localhost:3000/images/logo_general.png">
```

and

```
<%= image_tag("logo_general.png") %>
```

Why am I having problems loading images using the first way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because the correct tag to use is

```
<img>
```

And not

```
<images>
```

Comment: If the answer helped, press the tick on the left hand side of the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several differences:

1. The image_tag generates the HTML `<img>` tag, not `<images>`
2. The source path is based on your asset host and asset path, so images don't break if they change. The default is relative to root, e.g. /images/
3. image_tag gives you an alt attribute for proper accessibility.
4. In development mode, it adds a random number to the image as a convenience to prevent the browser from using a cached image in case you change it.
5. image_tag properly closes the tag. with `/>`.

You can try it out in the Rails Console.

```
image_tag("logo_general.png")
=> <img alt="Logo_general" src="/images/logo_general.png?1230601161" />
```